# Java regex replacement with and condition

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a question.
What I would like to do is, using Java regex, replace a "Or" sequence if it isn't an "Order" sequence. Thereby if the sequence starts with "Or" and it does not end with "der" I would like to do a replace:

E.g.:

- findByNameOrAge expected -> findByName Or Age
- findByNameOrderAge expected -> findByNameOrderAge (Keep the same value)

I've tried same regex sequence, however, without luck.

```
    String value = "findByNameOrAge";
    String value2 = "findByNameOrderByAge";
    String regex = "Or(?=^der)";
    System.out.println(value.replaceAll(regex, " or "));
    System.out.println(value2.replaceAll(regex, " or "));
```

Answer (score 4):

Your regex `(?=^der)` matches `Or` and  uses a positive lookahead to assert what follows is the start of the string `^` followed by `der`

Instead, you could use a negative lookahead `(?!` to assert that what follows `Or` is not `der` and then replace with `or`

`Or(?!der)`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HQRaC2/1)

`String regex = "Or(?!der)";`

[Java Demo](http://rextester.com/WYTJU34284)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:   `Or(?!der)`, it will check whether `Or` is followed by `der` or not. it will replace `Or` if it is not followed by `der`,skip otherwise.

```
String value = "findByNameOrAge";
String value2 = "findByNameOrderByAge";
String regex = "Or(?!der)";
System.out.println(value.replaceAll(regex, " or "));
System.out.println(value2.replaceAll(regex, " or "));
```

[check demo here](https://regex101.com/r/0MYuWc/1/)

**Explanation**

`Or(?!der)`

`Or` matches the characters Or literally (case sensitive)

Negative Lookahead `(?!der)`

Assert that the Regex below does not match

`der` matches the characters `der` literally (case sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

`String regex = "[Oo]r(?!der)";` use this as regular expression. It will also include the word "or" with uper case and lower case 'o'.